# How to safely transfer P2O5 waste from a round bottom flask to waste bottle?

Tags: safety

The $\ce{P2O5}$ is used as a neat desiccant in the round bottom flask as part of a vacuum system and is mainly solid with some liquification after use. Waiting for it all to liquify isn't practical, adding water directly seems dangerous, and trying to scoop it out is very difficult and dangerous for possible contact/exposure reasons.

Comment: Yes, indeed, dangerous. You should read the safety sheets before running a reaction, they usually contain the information for a proper disposal. And please tell us what RBF is.

Comment: The safety data sheet is at best vague and at worst useless, especially in specific cases like removal from a round bottom flask (RBF) where the substance is now in 2 phases and is mechanically difficult to manipulate out of the flask.

Comment: What type of chemistry is performed *prior* to the vacuum system? This may guide what to expect in this trap (no pun intended). Isn't there a colleague of yours you may contact who knows what is allowed in your local jurisdiction and instructed you in advance? As side note, [https://organicchemistrydata.org](https://organicchemistrydata.org/) compiled some resources to ease retrieving MSDS data [here](https://organicchemistrydata.org/links/#safety_resources) e.g., [this](http://www.cheminfo.org/Chemistry/MSDS_lookup/index.html), and [this](https://chemicalsafety.com/sds-search/).

Comment: It depends on the amount of substance. If there is only a couple of grams, water can be slowly added, drop by drop. Stop for a while  if the substance becomes too hot. Two hours should be enough to get rid of this stuff.

Comment: Fot an amateur: stay away and give the task someone professional. For a chemist this is a standard case. Of course a couple of grams (like in the previous comments) can be safely disposed of with a heavy current of tapwater. For a few hundred grams leave the RBF within a humid area for a couple of days, best for weeks then drain with again a heavy stream of water. With more then a few hundred grams you should have a professional who knows the best way to dispose of. You should respect chemicals and no way do something you are not experienced with. Be careful.